# Create nested elements dynamically using XQuery and xpath

Tags: xquery

How can we use path seperated by /(slash) for creating nested elements dynamically using xquery.

For example,

If  XML is like below structure

```
<Document> <Header> <Body> </Body> </Header> </Document>
```

and if the parameter is Document/Header/Footer then nodes should be created like below.

```
<Document> <Header> <Body> </Body> </Header> **<Footer> </Footer>** </Document>
```

Above is only example.Can any one help me in providing generic node creation based on input path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokenize the path into a sequence of strings. Traverse the input XML tree and path tree simultaneously. If at any point the path differs from the source tree, create a new subtree matching the remaining path:

```
declare function local:make-nested-elements(
  $element-names as xs:string*
) as element()*
{
  if (empty($element-names)) then ()
  else element { $element-names[1] } {
    local:make-nested-elements(subsequence($element-names, 2))
  }
};

declare function local:add-path(
  $xml as node()?,
  $paths as xs:string*
) as node()
{
  let $first := $paths[1]
  let $rest := subsequence($paths, 2)
  return
    if (empty($first)) then $xml
    else if ($xml instance of text()) then $xml
    else if (node-name($xml) = xs:QName($first))
    then element { $first } {
        $xml/@*,
        for $n in $xml/node()
        return local:add-path($n, $rest)
      }
    else element { node-name($xml) } {
        $xml/@*, $xml/node(),
        local:make-nested-elements($paths)
      }
};
```

**Input**:

```
let $xml := 
  <Document> 
    <Header>This is a Header
      <Body>Body message</Body> 
    </Header> 
  </Document>
let $path := "Document/Header/Footer/keep/nesting"
return local:add-path($xml, tokenize($path, '/'))
```

**Output**:

```
<Document>
   <Header>This is a Header
     <Body>Body message
        <Footer>
          <keep>
            <nesting/>
          </keep>
        </Footer>
      </Body>
    </Header>
</Document>
```

Comment: The above code is generating required node at different level.For example path like "Document/Header/Footer" should create as sibling to Header not as Body element Sibling.

Comment: @TaarzanT Then how would the algorithm know whether `/` means "child" or "sibling"? By almost every convention `/` means "child", so I think it's best to keep it that way, and instead update your path to create a sibling to Header: `Document/Footer`.